# Reauthorize permissions to Google apps script after password change

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I just changed my password for my Gmail ID but this also stopped all my script triggers. I had to manually run the script again and authorize the script to send emails and other permissions. Is there a way around this or do I have to authorize the Apps script every time I change my password? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

there is no workaround. you must reauthorize scripts that run as the owner. this was a recent change by google's oauth handling (not just apps script)

see http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.pe/2015/12/increased-account-security-via-oauth2.html

UPDATE:

https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2016/09/update-increased-account-security-via.html