# How to re-authorize Google Apps Scripts after password reset?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I wrote a script that uses a service account and OAuth2 for Apps Scripts to disable auto-forwarding and enable IMAP on a domain user's gmail settings. The script works.

However, when I change the user's password. It stops working and gives me response code 401.

From other other question,  suggested that I re-authorize the scripts. [Reauthorize permissions to Google apps script after password change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39497059/reauthorize-permissions-to-google-apps-script-after-password-change)

How do you manually re-authorize the script?

I see the user's "access_token" for the Gmail API in the Script properties but not sure how to change it.

Comment: Do what you did the first time to get Auth?

Answer (score 0):

Normally a service account is independent of the user changing their password.  This has always been one of the key points of service accounts and Oauth2 even if the user changes their password you will still have access.

However this no longer works for some of the Google apis.  Gmail is one if them if the user changes their password then the access token and the Oauth2 refresh token will no longer work until the user reauthenticates the application.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of super-simple projects, each one is just one file a few lines long, so my guess if yours is more complicated is you should probably open whichever file gets executed on triggers or whatever).

Anyway after I changed the password on my Google account those scripts kept failing. What worked for me was:

1. Go to the [Google Apps Script homepage](https://script.google.com/home)
2. For whatever projects are failing, open the project and then open the main/only source code file (depends on if your scripts are more complicated than mine)
3. In the editor, just click *Run* at the top. That should trigger an OAuth request saying it needs permissions for your account blah blah blah. Obviously, give it access.
4. Either sit back with beverage of choice (if it works now) or bash head against keyboard (if it didn't fix it).

I have no idea if you'd have to run other script files in the editor, but can't hurt, right? Unless your script is designed to hurt.